# How to apply automation on “Windows authentication dialog” and login into the web application using c# , selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, modal-dialog

I am trying to login in the web application through the Windows authentication popup. I tried to switch the window using “driver.SwitchTo().Alert()”.
And I also tried to use “driver.get(“http//user:pass@siteurl.com”)” but nothing is working. Always getting the same exception “Model dialog Present”.
How can I find the text box and enter the credential.
I am using .net(c#) with selenium webdriver and working in Visual studio.

Comment: What Webdriver are you using? What windows authentication model are you using server side?

Comment: Try to add // at the beginning of driver.get(“http//user:pass@siteurl.com”) with the domain name :
"//domain\user:password@test.com"

Comment: I am not able to access driver.get method . I am using InterneExplorerDriver . IS there any other alternative method to do login through widows authentication dilog box using c#.

Comment: WE can not give uaername and password in a url. for maintaining security we can not use it.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are:

May be your statement is wrong somewhere so just revisit your code once again. As the pop up appeared is an java script pop up and It's called basic authentication pop up. There is no way for you to switch over that and try entering credentials.

You can try playing with `http://` and `https://` as some basic authentication works only with `https://`

Suggested syntax: `driver.Navigate().To("http://UserId:Pass@siteUrl.com");`

see if it works.

Comment: Dialog box which I was getting , was a window base popup. Selenium webdriver can not handle windows base popup itself. I used AutoIt for handling the windows based popup. Problem is solved.